# Does Ape Framework have contract verification workflow?

Tags: web3js, blockchain

Brownie, Hardhat, and Truffle all provide contract verification as part of the core library capabilities. I do not see that Ape Framework have a dedicated module in their docs for verifying contracts.

https://docs.apeworx.io/ape/stable/userguides/quickstart.html

Answer (score 2):

Ape Framework is a [plug-in](https://docs.apeworx.io/ape/stable/userguides/developing_plugins.html) oriented smart contract deployment tool. There is actually a dedicated Etherscan plugin located [here](https://github.com/ApeWorX/ape-etherscan).

Set your Etherscan API Key:

```
export ETHERSCAN_API_KEY=SAMPLE_KEY
```

Publish the source contract code by passing the `publish` argument:

```
from ape import accounts, project

account = accounts.load("testnetacct")

account.deploy(project.MyContract, publish=True)
```